# How to load helpers before JS source files in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jasmine, gon

This question is specifically because I'm using `gon`, but conceptually it could apply to other cases, so I've tried to broaden it a bit. Gon is a nifty gem that allows you to declare a variable in your Rails controller and then use it in your Javascript. For example:

```
def index
  gon.this = "that"
end

// index.html
<script>
  console.log(gon.this)
  // would print "that"
</script>
```

Specifically how this happens is that Gon injects a piece of script that declares a global variable, like so:

```
<script>
  window.gon = {}
  gon.this = "that"
</script>
```

The code that I'm using Jasmine to test looks like this:

```
// test.js
function loadProperPage() {
  if (gon.this == "that") {
    ...
  } else {
    ...
  }
}
```

So as you can see, `gon` is used immediately! My problem is that Jasmine keeps saying that `gon` has not been defined, so I'm not sure how to "inject" it in a way that's semantically sensible. The only way that I can think of where it makes sense is to create a fake `.js` file and require it as a source file in my `javascript.yml` before I load the file I'm testing. I.e., it would look like this:

```
src_files:
  - assets/gon_variables.js
  - assets/test.js
```

But this is not a sustainable solution, because then I can't change the dummy variables in the `gon_variables.js` file for different specs...

**By that last sentence, what I mean is that I've been troubleshooting, and discovered that declaring `gon` variables in either the fixture or the spec file itself will NOT work**. I.e. both the below do NOT solve the problem

```
/////// spec file approach

//spec file

describe...
  beforeEach(function() {
    gon.this = "that"
  })
})

/////// fixture file approach

// spec file
describe...
  beforeEach(function() {
    loadFixtures('test.html')
  })
})

// test.html fixture
<head>
   <script>
     var gon = {permission: "new"}
   </script>
</head>
<body>
  ...
</body>
```

Which brings me back to my question. My debugging apparently shows that the JS files in `jasmine.yml` are loaded BEFORE either the fixtures or the spec file (and its before actions). Therefore, how else can you load dynamic code before the JS files in `jasmine.yml`? Is there a helper that I can use or... ? Keep in mind the whole point of this is that I'd like to change the code I'm loading before the JS files depending on the spec. I.e., sometimes I want to have `gon.this = "that"` but other times I'd like `gon.this = "those"`

Comment: The function you're trying to test, loadProperPage, is that inside a document ready block? Like, do you call it with something like `$(function() { loadProperPage() });` ?

Comment: Yes, I have several functions that use `gon`, some are definitely called on document.ready, others are only called when a button is pushed, but the former are the issue